# Publishing site without workflow?

Tags: workflow, publishing-site

I want publishing sites without workflow. Let me explaint my requirement like this. In my publishing webs content authors only should approve/reject items for content authoring. No need for workflow in Checking-in or Publishing items.

How can i achieve this. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Team site, select the required options and enable publishing. The workflow isn't part of the Team site template, this is really the only major difference.

Comment: Thanks but i need to create from publishing site template. Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: You could make a feature stapler for the publishing portal template, this would remove the workflow from the library. The code for removing the approval workflow is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishand/archive/2008/08/27/how-to-add-remove-and-start-workflow-programmatically.aspx, Check-In/out and Publish are part of the publishing feature, which if you want you can remove.

Comment: so; even if i remove the "approval workflow" from library, the workflow starting screen still pops-up when selecting "publishing major version" option in library?

Comment: Well you can do it manually if you are unsure. In the library settings, turn off versioning, and then go to the workflow settings and remove the approval workflow.